# Accessing base class protected method from child class ref & obj, parent class ref & child class obj, parent class ref & obj and super

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, java-8

Let's say I have a class `Animal` which have a protected function `eat()`. I want to access `eat()` function in `Cat` class that extends Animal class in different package.
There are 4 ways out of which 2 are working and 2 are not, I am looking for some explanation of this behaviour.

```
package package1;

public class Animal {
    protected void eat(){
        System.out.println("Animal is eating");
    }
}
```

```
package package2;

import package1.Animal;

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public void provideFood(){
        Animal cat = new Animal();
        System.out.println("food provided");
        cat.eat(); //---> it doesn't compile

        Animal cat1 = new Cat();
        System.out.println("food provided");
        cat1.eat(); //--> it doesn't compile

        Cat cat2 = new Cat();
        System.out.println("food provided");
        cat2.eat();   //--> it compiles

        System.out.println("food provided");
        super.eat();   //--> it compiles
    }
}
```

I tried the code in local to see which one works but I am looking for explanation

Comment: Receiver type must be the subclass, in this case `Cat`. `Cat` can't call `.eat()` on a `Dog`.